# AWS Xray - Differenciate 2 SQS queues

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I'm currently working in a project in AWS for the first time and i'm having trouble having something relevant in XRay.

The structure of my project is the following :

I have an API Gateway with a endpoint, when called, this endpoint pushes a message to an SQS queue (Queue A) and this triggers a Lambda that treats the message and pushes a message to another SQS queue (Queue B). Following this architecture, i should get something like this in Xray :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYRIK.png

but what i get instead is this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMCMB.png

For some reason, the Xray trace can't understand that my SQS queues A and B are two different queues and just puts an "SQS" element, so visualy, you could understand that my lambda function pushes a message to the same queue, which is not the case.

To enable the XRay inside my lambda so that it can see the SendMessage() done in the code i added the following nuget packages : AWSXRayRecorder.Core and AWSXRayRecorder.Handlers.AwsSdk and a simple thing in the constructor following AWS documentation to enable XRay inside a lambda in .NET :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/trKeU.png

Any tips on what to do so that XRay can understand that SQS Queue A and SQS Queue B are two separate entities ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue with AWS SDK v2 for Java, and it was fixed by this PR: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/pull/374

The fix will be released in the next version of the X-Ray SDK for Java.